# Why we need ML batch execution and update resource option in azure data factory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

Why we need to ML Batch Execution and ML Update resource option in Data factory ? How this can be used to retrain machine learning when updating a blob file ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ml Batch Execution- to call retraining experiment and get a .ilearner file as output.
ML Update Resource- Use the above .ilearner as input and call patch endpoint of predictive web service to Update resource.